# Build server availability to run powershell on step 1 Visual Studio Online

Tags: azure-pipelines

Problem definition:-

I need to turn on the aws instance on build step 1 and after build deployment turn it off to save the cost.

Now what I am trying to do is adding build step 1 (PowerShell) in VSO to turn on the AWS instance but it's saying waiting for build agent and build step does not starts. Its same build agent configured against the build which I am trying to turn on. I think build needs available agent to run even it needs to execute the powershell.

Is there any efficient solution to this problem ?

Comment: You use the Hosted Agent to build or your own build agent? Could other build definitions could be run using the same build agent? If not adding the first step, the build could run well?

Comment: Can you still see this issue now? There was an issue with hosted build agent before but it is fixed now. Refer to this link for details: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsoservice/?p=13196. If you can still see this issue, can you share a screenshot?